# Realtime data and Openlayers 3: Batch moving features

Tags: javascript, batch-processing, openlayers-3

I have a hashtable I am trying to use in an vector layer so this is what I made:

```
var make = [], remove = [];
for (var key in data) {
  var val = data[key];
  if (featureCache[key]) {
    if (val._ts > featureCache[key]._ts) {
      var geom = featureCache[key].getGeometry();
```

The problem starts here. From what I have found out so far I have two options:

```
      geom.setCoordinates(latlng([val.Latitude, val.Longitude]));
      geom.flatCoordinates = latlng([val.Latitude, val.Longitude]);
```

However the first one bubbles up and makes the map render, this is a problem because I have over 1500 features and I plan on using more.
The second line gives me assertion failed, and I dont know how to debug it.

```
      featureCache[key]._ts = val._ts;
    }
  } else {
    make.push(featureCache[key] =
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(latlng([val.Latitude,val.Longitude]))
      })
    );
    featureCache[key]._ts = val._ts;
  }
}
source.addFeatures(make);
```

This needs to be run every other second or so because I want the data to be as realtime as possible.

And if this is a really stupid way do do it, I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you could do it with the new API, but you could try this:

1. clone an old geometry and update it, do this for each
2. add the clone to a collection that OL is not aware of (avoids the map render / updates)
3. once that collection is ready, remove the old collection from OL and set the new (batch)

Doing this for several thousand items should work pretty fast on 'modern' browsers as you set it only once. The key point is to avoid triggering updates while you update each entry.

Maybe there are ways to avoid the bubbling/events to allow for batch updates (no triggering of map render for each change) ?